# Closures in a multiline string

Tags: groovy

I am not sure if it is even possible, but I wish to add a closure with a loop in a multiline string that would generate another multiline string at each loop.

```
 String body = """\
    Total Invoice Amount: £${totalInvAmt}

    ${quantities.each { qty ->
        Offer offer = Offer.findByShoppingItem(qty.shoppingItem)
        def itemDetails = """\
            Name: ${offer.itemName}
            Qty: $qty.value"""

        itemDetails
    }}
    """
```

The closure will loop over a list of items and for each item concatenate an multistring.  All this produces is

```
Total Invoice Amount: £1100

    [100, 100]
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Why would you want to nest them inside a string like this, guaranteeing illegibility? Also, you're calling `each`, which doesn't magically do anything other than iterate; `each` returns the collection you iterate over.

Comment: you should turn this around: do your data collections and build a proper "model" -- then render with a string (unless you want to generate groovy code... and even then)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's pseudo-code that does something closer to what you want, delta I'm not going to try to reproduce your data structs etc. without an SSCCE.

Nutshell: `each` iterates, you want to `collect`.

```
body = """
    Total Invoice Amount: £${totalInvAmt}

    ${quantities.collect { qty ->
        offer = Offer.findByShoppingItem(qty.shoppingItem)
        """
            Name: ${offer.itemName}
            Qty: ${qty.value}
        """
    }.join('\n')}
"""
```

I'd urge you never to do anything like this; it's abusive. At a minimum the inner string generation should be handled in its own method, not wedged in the middle of *another* string. It's difficult to read and maintain.

Comment: Thanks, yes you are right, and I will take your advice.

Comment: @malc please remember that it will always be well received to provide a good SSCCE.

Comment: "I'd urge you never to do anything like this" - Indeed.  I would not advise folks to do anything like that either.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a template engine.

```
import groovy.text.GStringTemplateEngine

def music = [:]
music.Riverside = ['Second Life Syndrome', 'Anno Domini High Definition']
music.Beardfish = ['Destined Solitare', 'Mammoth']

def templateText = '''
Number Of Artists: ${music.size()}.

<% music.each { artist, albums -> %>\
Artist Name: ${artist}
    <% albums.each { albumTitle -> %>\
    Album Title: ${albumTitle}
    <% } %>
<% } %>
'''

def engine = new GStringTemplateEngine()
def template = engine.createTemplate(templateText).make(music:music)

println template.toString()
```

That will produce output like this:

```
Number Of Artists: 2.

Artist Name: Riverside  
    Album Title: Second Life Syndrome    
    Album Title: Anno Domini High Definition    

Artist Name: Beardfish    
    Album Title: Destined Solitare    
    Album Title: Mammoth
```

You have a number of options and a good bit of flexibility in how you put that together.  See http://beta.groovy-lang.org/templating.html for more info.

I hope that helps.